# Looping data inside highchart.js using type column chart

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I have and array of data and I want it to loop inside data[] for presenting a chart using `Highchart.js` chart type is `column`.

When passing data from controller to view I have printed the graph using below code but now since the data is coming from ajax request how can I process the data to make a graph.

I have created one `results` array and loop through each data and pushed inside the results and passed it directly to data  in `generateGraph` function, but the graph is not working.

I am using ajax request to fetch data and pass it to the function defined for generating graph, below is my array data format.

`Ajax request`

```
$.ajax({
    url : someurl,
    dataType: "json",
    method: 'post',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#loader").show();
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        $("#loader").hide();
        generateGraph(data);
    }
});
```

`array data`

```
[
    {
        name: "Bestozyme",
        number: "1",
    },
    {
        name: "Sinarest-PD",
        number: "1",
    },
    {
        name: "Azithral",
        number: "1",
    },
    {
        name: "Lecope-M-Kid",
        number: "1",
    },
    {
        name: "Calpol (250 MG)",
        number: "1",
    },
    {
        name: "Calapure",
        number: "1",
    },
]
```

`using php code in series` - data passing through rendering views from controller.

```
series: [{
    name: 'Medicine',
    color: '#F15C80',
    data: [
        <?php    
        foreach($data['medicine'] as $medi){
        ?>
            ['<?php echo $medi['name'];?>',<?php echo $medi['number'];?>], 
        <?php
        }
        ?>        
        
    ],
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        rotation: -90,
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        align: 'right',
        format: '{point.y}', // one decimal
        y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
        style: {
            fontSize: '13px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
    }
}]
```

`highchart.js`

```
function generateGraph(item){
    let results=[];
    item.forEach((val) => {
        results.push([val.name,val.number])
    });
    
    Highcharts.chart('medicine', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: ' '
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Medicine'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}</b>'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Medicine',
            color: '#F15C80',
            data: results,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                format: '{point.y}', // one decimal
                y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        }]
    });
}
```

Comment: data: [
        <?php    
        foreach($data['medicine'] as $medi){
        ?>
            ['<?php echo $medi['name'];?>',<?php echo $medi['number'];?>], 
        <?php
        }
        ?>        
        
    ],

you have to check your result in view source or share that out i will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that Highcharts requires the `y` data value in a number format, not string. Try this approach:

```
let results=[];
item.forEach((val) => {
    results.push([val.name, parseInt(val.number)])
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lds9cyau/

Comment: Wedzel thanks for the help. it worked, just because I didn't do parseInt(val.number) it was not working..Thanks you